# Calculate start time for the repeated AlarmManager

Tags: android, time, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I'm working on an Android application which uses AlarmManager as follows:

```java
Long startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
alarm.setRepeating(
     AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
     startTime,
     15* 60 * 1000,
     PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

I want to calculate the `startTime`. Let's say I need to run some code repeatedly after 15 minutes, but this after 15 minutes should not start from now (current time) but right from the next slot. Whenever I enable the alarm it should start it from the next available slot (which means I need to calculate the start time).

Example 1: If current time is 10:8, then the first run should be at 10:15.

Example 2: If it's 10:17, then first the run should be at 10:30.

Example 3: If it's 10:38, then the first run should be at 10:45.

As AlarmManager takes 2 time parameters in milliseconds, the first one when to start the alarm and the second as the repeat time in milliseconds (15 minutes).

If it's still unclear then I would say I need to run my code when minutes of the device are either one of the following values:
00, 15, 30, 45 irrespective of the hour value of the device.

Answer (score 0):

First, bear in mind that Doze mode and app standby on Android 6.0+ will mean that you will not always get control when you want.

That being said, you need to adjust `startTime`. Call `get(Calendar.MINUTE)` on it to get the current minutes. Determine how many minutes you need to add to get to the next quarter-hour. Then, call `add(Calendar.MINUTE, ...)`, where `...` is the amount you need to add to get the minute value to the next quarter-hour. Using `add()` will handle incrementing the hour, day, etc. as needed.

Comment: Well that is what I wanted to know. Actually i am looking for some equation. which can tell me which slot(in this case quarter) to set as start time. I can use if condition on minutes to decide the quarter but the interval is not static it could be in (15  , 30 , 60, dynamic). well more if conditions could be applied but solution must be dynamic.

Comment: @PHPAvenger: `if (minutes<15) { offset=15-minutes; } else if (minutes<30) { offset=30-minutes; } ...`